# how to make multi module Ear project in eclipse and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i am new to Ear kind project i can make a war project now i want to add my all war project in a Ear project by using maven but not able to get success my pom.xml file of Ear project gives me the error
and i am not able to get that, if any one has the solution please help.

thanks in adv.

Comment: this is the error file show me

Comment: If anyone has the solution to the error you are not even posting?

Comment: Have you tried following a tutorial like this? http://daveshepherd.co.uk/2012-06-multi-module-project-maven What is the error you get? Do you have your config (poms, project structure, etc.) somewhere accessible online?

Comment: thanks for help, but i am still getting the error in maven install Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.7:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project EyewatchEar: Artifact[war:com.EyewatchEar.ear:ewfront] is not a dependency of the project. -> [Help 1] any idea.

Comment: i did that for more please visit this http://nitinipmalik.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-make-multi-module-project-or-ear.html